# How to set multiple project owners in MS ProjectServer

Tags: sharepoint, ms-project, project-server, psi

I'm trying to configure a owner-like user in MS ProjectServer (2003). Though I can grant every permission to the user, for certain services (via PSI), like *Statusing.ReadStatusTimephasedData*, it seems to require to be the project owner.

I've tried to configure category permissions to consider RBS but no results either.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you asking about configuring permissions for a user? Seems like you would want to give the user permission by using the "Project Manager" permission template. Ex: by using this screen http://server/pwa/_layouts/PWA/Admin/AddModifyUser.aspx

Comment: It's not a matter of permissions. This service requires the user to be related to the project. If you are a team member, it returns your actuals (work, cost, ...). But if you are the project owner (user who created the project) you get the actuals of every assigned resource.

I need to get every project timephased actuals without changing the owner and without TimeSheets. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this! I have developed a PSI extension to get the data I need.